# array_slice page numbering

Tags: php, arrays

This script takes every image in a folder and shows it on a webpage. Is there a way to show like an simple page number like 1,2,3,4,5 every 10 images or so? everything I tried thus far is not working.

```
   <?php

        # To prevent browser error output
        header('Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=UTF-8');
        # Path to image folder
        $imagefolder = 'img/';
        # Show only these file types in the image folder
        $imagetypes = '{*.jpg,*.JPG,*.JPEG,*.png,*.PNG,*.gif,*.GIF}';
        # Add images to array
        $images = glob($imagefolder.$imagetypes, GLOB_BRACE);
        # Sort the images based on its 'last modified' time stamp
        $sortedImages = array();
        $count = count($images);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
            $sortedImages[date ('YmdHis', filemtime($images[$i])).$i] = $images[$i];
        }

        # Set to 'false' if you want the oldest images to appear first
        $newest_images_first = true;
        # Sort images in array
        if($newest_images_first) {
            krsort($sortedImages);
        } else {
            ksort($sortedImages);
        }

        # Generate the HTML output
        writeHtml('<ul class="ins-imgs">');
        foreach ($sortedImages as $image) {
            # Get the name of the image, stripped from image folder path and file type extension
            $name = 'Image name: '.substr($image,strlen($imagefolder),strpos($image, '.')-strlen($imagefolder));
            # Get the 'last modified' time stamp, make it human readable
            $last_modified = '(last modified: '.date('F d Y H:i:s', filemtime($image)).')';
            # Begin adding
            writeHtml('<li class="ins-imgs-li">');
            writeHtml('<div class="ins-imgs-label">'.$name.' '.$last_modified.'</div>');
            writeHtml('<div class="ins-imgs-img"><a name="'.$image.'" href="#'.$image.'">');
            writeHtml('<img src="'.$image.'" alt="'. $name.'" title="'. $name.'">');
            writeHtml('</a></div>');
            writeHtml('</li>');
        }
        writeHtml('</ul>');
        writeHtml('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ins-imgs.css">');
        # Convert HTML to JS
        function writeHtml($html) {
            echo "document.write('".$html."');\n";



        }

    ?>
```

Comment: google for `php pagination` and you'll find plenty of tutorials

Comment: issue is all  I can find is with a database. I dont have a database just the array on its own.

Comment: I've used this simple loop for my pagination which uses $_GET value to retrive the page number: `for($i = (($page-1)*$perPage); $i < min(($page*$perPage), $total); $i++)`...
Obviously `$i` is the **index**, `$page` is the page number from the url, `$perPage` is the number of elements per page to show (in my case is a constant)

Comment: I dont think I can implement that within this script tho.

Comment: @Dylan_R Why not? You just need to change your `foreach` loop and add some page number logic.

Comment: You can use this to create a new array of "thisPage" elements containing only the elements 11 to 20, 21 to 30 and so on... then loop through the new array elements with your `foreach` so you will have **sortedImages** array with *N* elements and **thisPageSortedImages** array displayed with 10 elements

Comment: @slicedtoad well lets say it like this. I am a scrub in php. I am still on school to learn it aswell. I dont have that logic in my head yet. might believe it or not but this script that I use took me months to make.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you said you are not a `PHP` master I'll show my solution and explain it step by step.
I hope you can find it helpful.

Here is the loop I use for pagination:

```
for($i = (($page-1)*$perPage); $i < min(($page*$perPage), $total); $i++) {
    }
```

I'll gonna use this to create a new array with the elements **11-20**, **21-30** and so on.

First of all I removed the `.$i` in your `$sortedImages` array's index (**15th** row of your code)

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $sortedImages[date ('YmdHis', filemtime($images[$i]))] = $images[$i]; #15th Row
}
```

because it makes the index a bit messy (it is necessary for a next step).

Then I create a new  array with **0 to N** indexes which makes the code tidy (I do it to change your code as less as possible) and then I populate it with the elements of `$sortedImages` array.

```
$k = 0; # The new index
$newArray = array(); # The new array
foreach($sortedImages as $soImg) {
    $newArray[$k] = $soImg; 
    $k++;
}
```

Finally the pagination's implementation:

```
$page = $_GET["page"];
$perPage = 3;
$total = $count;

for ($i = (($page-1)*$perPage); $i < min(($page*$perPage), $total); $i++) {
    $newSortedImages[$i] = $newArray[$i];
}
```

Variables:

- `$page = $_GET["page"];` is the page number retrived from the url (`$_GET[]` is a [superglobal array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php))
- `$perPage` is the number of elements to show per page
- `$total = $count;` is the number of `$images` array (13th line)

The loop:

- `$i = (($page-1)*$perPage)` is the start of the loop, if the page is **1** the loop should start from **0** then the expression `(($page-1)*$perPage)` makes it work.
- `$i < min(($page*$perPage), $total)` is the end of the loop, [`min()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.min.php) finds the lowest value between its arguments, it is helpful when e.g. the last page contains 4 elements while 6 are expected.

Then you just need to change the array to loop through in 29th row of your code from `$sortedImages` to `$newSortedImages`.

For pagination controls use this:

```
$nextPage = $page + 1;
$prevPage = $page - 1;
```

Here is the new code implementation:

```
# To prevent browser error output
header('Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=UTF-8');
# Path to image folder
$imagefolder = 'img/';
# Show only these file types in the image folder
$imagetypes = '{*.jpg,*.JPG,*.JPEG,*.png,*.PNG,*.gif,*.GIF}';
# Add images to array
$images = glob($imagefolder.$imagetypes, GLOB_BRACE);
# Sort the images based on its 'last modified' time stamp
$sortedImages = array();
$count = count($images);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $sortedImages[date ('YmdHis', filemtime($images[$i])).$i] = $images[$i];
}

# Set to 'false' if you want the oldest images to appear first
$newest_images_first = true;
# Sort images in array
if($newest_images_first) {
    krsort($sortedImages);
} else {
    ksort($sortedImages);
}

# Now I give an index from 0 to N to the new array to make it work with pagination loop
$k = 0; # The new index
$newArray = array(); # The new array
foreach($sortedImages as $soImg) {
    $newArray[$k] = $soImg;
    $k++;
}

$page = $_GET["page"];
$perPage = 3;
$total = $count;
for ($i = (($page-1)*$perPage); $i < min(($page*$perPage), $total); $i++) {
    $newSortedImages[$i] = $newArray[$i];
}

# Generate the HTML output
writeHtml('<ul class="ins-imgs">');
foreach ($newSortedImages as $image) {
    # Get the name of the image, stripped from image folder path and file type extension
    $name = 'Image name: '.substr($image,strlen($imagefolder),strpos($image, '.')-strlen($imagefolder));
    # Get the 'last modified' time stamp, make it human readable
    $last_modified = '(last modified: '.date('F d Y H:i:s', filemtime($image)).')';
    # Begin adding
    writeHtml('<li class="ins-imgs-li">');
    writeHtml('<div class="ins-imgs-label">'.$name.' '.$last_modified.'</div>');
    writeHtml('<div class="ins-imgs-img"><a name="'.$image.'" href="#'.$image.'">');
    writeHtml('<img src="'.$image.'" alt="'. $name.'" title="'. $name.'">');
    writeHtml('</a></div>');
    writeHtml('</li>');
}
writeHtml('</ul>');
writeHtml('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ins-imgs.css">');
# Convert HTML to JS
function writeHtml($html) {
    echo "document.write('".$html."');\n";
}
```

For page numbering you have to know the total of elements and divide it by `$perPage` elements, obviously the result must be an integer, so you'll gonna use [`ceil()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php)

From [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php)

> Returns the next highest integer value by rounding up value if necessary.

```
$pages = ceil($count / $perPage);
```

And then use this to display peges numbers:

```
for($i = 1; $i <= $pages; $i++) {
    writeHtml('<a href="?page=' . $i . '">' . $i . '</a> ');
}
```

Comment: highly appreciated good sir. it might be a difficult thing to do or even ask but is it possible to have numbering? like 1 2 3 4 5?

Comment: I'm glad to be of help ;) Of course it is possible, I'll update my answer as soon as possible

Comment: haha this kinda made me laugh I got exactly what I want. but I think there are too many pages heres why: http://i.imgur.com/OaNrg2F.png Is there a way to limit this? to like 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 .... and then when u press on lets say 8 u get a new row?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a database to implement simple pagination.

```
$currentpage = $_GET['p'];
for ($i = ($currentpage*$pageSize); $i<sortedImages as $image) {

  // your HTML output here

}

for($i = 0; $i < $sortedImages/$pageSize; $i++){
  writeHtml('<a href=/?p='.$i + 1.'/>');
}
```

That's just an example, probably won't work if you cut 'n paste. But there to give you a good idea of how it could be implemented.

Comment: isn't it possible with a simple pagination function or something? I have been trying to tweak this for 2 hours now and I cant seem to get it to work. I should have said that my php knowledge is below average.

Comment: You will need to write code if you want to do something.

Comment: Well ofcourse but if I dont get the logic behind it. its kinda hard to do so.